# GET friendships/show with rtweet

Tags: r, api, twitter, rtweet

I tried to find a way to use the **rtweet** package to perform a request to [GET friendships/show](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-show) from the Twitter REST API, in order to analyse the relationship between two users. However, I could not make it work (I did find `lookup_friendships()`, but it does not do what I want). Is it possible to do that with **rtweet**, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been added to [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet), so there should be at least somewhat reasonable access to the "friendships/show" API via `lookup_friendships()`–and, bonus, it just got accepted in version `0.6.0` now on CRAN now!

Required inputs are `source` and `target` (can be screen names or user IDs). If only one user is provided to either `source` or `target`, then any number of users–save Twitter API rate limits–can be passed in the other parameter.

```
fds <- lookup_friendships(
  source = "realDonaldTrump",
  target = c("DRUDGE_REPORT", "seanhannity", "HuffPost", "maddow", "cnn")
)
> fds
# A tibble: 60 x 4
   relationship            user       variable           value
          <chr>           <chr>          <chr>           <chr>
 1       source   DRUDGE_REPORT             id        25073877
 2       source   DRUDGE_REPORT         id_str        25073877
 3       source   DRUDGE_REPORT    screen_name realDonaldTrump
 4       source   DRUDGE_REPORT      following            TRUE
 5       source   DRUDGE_REPORT    followed_by           FALSE
 6       source   DRUDGE_REPORT live_following           FALSE
 7       source   DRUDGE_REPORT         can_dm           FALSE
 8       target realDonaldTrump             id        14669951
 9       target realDonaldTrump         id_str        14669951
10       target realDonaldTrump    screen_name   DRUDGE_REPORT
# ... with 50 more rows
>
```

It's also possible to specify more than one user in both `source` and `target` parameters. However, if the length of both parameters is greater than 1, then the vectors must be of equal length.

```
## vector of multiple users
usrs <- c(
  "realDonaldTrump", "DRUDGE_REPORT", "seanhannity", "HuffPost", "maddow", "cnn"
)
fds <- lookup_friendships(
  source = usrs, 
  target = usrs
)
> fds
# A tibble: 72 x 4
   relationship            user       variable           value
          <chr>           <chr>          <chr>           <chr>
 1       source realDonaldTrump             id        25073877
 2       source realDonaldTrump         id_str        25073877
 3       source realDonaldTrump    screen_name realDonaldTrump
 4       source realDonaldTrump      following           FALSE
 5       source realDonaldTrump    followed_by           FALSE
 6       source realDonaldTrump live_following           FALSE
 7       source realDonaldTrump         can_dm            TRUE
 8       target realDonaldTrump             id        25073877
 9       target realDonaldTrump         id_str        25073877
10       target realDonaldTrump    screen_name realDonaldTrump
# ... with 62 more rows
```

There hasn't been a lot of time to test this yet. If you run into problems, try setting `parse = FALSE`. You'll be left to wrangling the returned data by yourself, but it might help avoid errors in internal parsing.

```
fds <- lookup_friendships(
      source = usrs, 
      target = usrs,
      parse = FALSE
    )
> str(fds, 3)
List of 6
 $ realDonaldTrump:List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
 $ DRUDGE_REPORT  :List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
 $ seanhannity    :List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
 $ HuffPost       :List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
 $ maddow         :List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
 $ cnn            :List of 1
  ..$ relationship:List of 2
  .. ..$ source:List of 16
  .. ..$ target:List of 7
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the [`get_friends()`](http://rtweet.info/reference/get_friends.html) or [`get_followers()`](http://rtweet.info/reference/get_followers.html) functions.

Comment: These don't perform the queries I want. `get_friends()` uses [GET friends/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friends-ids) and `get_followers()`uses [GET followers/ids](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids). Also, just to clarify, I am not looking for a solution that improvises a whole lot (I can make it work myself using httr, httpuv and jsonlite). I actually was wondering if there is a convenient solution implemented in **rtweet** already.

Comment: Ah I see. I jumped too fast on it. Looking briefly through the [documentation](http://rtweet.info/reference/index.html), it doesn't look like they've implemented that GET request. [`lookup_friendship()`](http://rtweet.info/reference/lookup_friendships.html) might be the closest, but that is just [`GET friendships/lookup`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet/blob/master/R/friends.R#L272) underneath. Maybe submit a feature request?